# Ignore filename extension for child_process fork using node-dev and Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, child-process, node-dev

I have a project written in Typescript, and I'm using `node-dev` alongside `ts-node` in my local enviroment for development. I'm using `child_process`'s `fork` method to instantiate a subprocess, like so:

`fork(path.join(__dirname, './worker.ts'));`

This works fine, and I can even set breakpoints in VS Code for the worker.

The problem is that when building (transpiling) my project, a `MODULE_NOT_FOUND` exception is thrown because `worker.ts` turned into `worker.js`. Initially, mi idea was to omit the file extension when forking (`fork(path.join(__dirname, './worker'));`), but if I do so, when running the project with `node-dev`, it throws a `MODULE_NOT_FOUND` because it can't resolve the file if the extension is not present.

Is there any workaround for this? Maybe an extra configuration option for `node-dev`?

I'm on Windows 10 using node v12.22.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple solution I suggest would be to read in the current file type. The compiled files should end with ".js" while the source files end with ".ts". Using the [path.extname methode](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_extname_path) in combination with [__filename](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_filename) you can easily extract that file extension and simply concat it to your file name.

```
fork(path.join(__dirname, './worker' + path.extname(__filename)));
```

Comment: I ended up checking if the `ts` file exists and falling back to the `js` one, but I think your approach is cleaner and more efficient. It's workaround and not a proper solution, I think. Should I choose it as the answer to the question?

Comment: Trying for .ts first and then for .js breaks if you compile your .js code in the same directory as your .ts files, which is the standard for the tsc. Also checking if a file exists that later in run time probably never exists, sounds like a bit of overhead.

Comment: Well, my approach works, because in my case the built js files end up in a different directory than my ts files. Anyway, you approach is certainly better.